# Java StackOverflowException when calling java.util.ArrayList.grow

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, arraylist, stack-overflow

I am writing an A* path finding algorithm for class. It works perfectly, I am able to click my character and move them to the correct location. However, after running for about 30 seconds of enemies also calling out to the A* algorithm it throws a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`.

The call directly before this is to the ArrayList library function grow. I can't imagine what I am doing wrong, as I am instantiating the object and am just calling `ArrayList.add(Node);`

What I am thinking is happening is that there are many ai characters that rely on this functionality, and after many of them calling to it, the program runs out of memory and surpasses the maximum stack size allocated for the program. However, Eclipse is not saying that Java ran out of memory or anything like this, which I would imagine would happen if the program actually ran out of memory.

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Or am I running out of memory? If so, is there a way to increase my allocated memory (I can see that I have tons of RAM left)? Or is there a better way that I could be storing my data to reduce memory loads?

Thanks! Here is the code I have currently written up, please let me know if there is any more information needed.

```
public class AStar {

    class Node
    {
        public double x, y, g, h;
        public Node parent;

        public Node(double _x, double _y, double _g, double _h, Node _parent)
        {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
            g = _g;
            h = _h;
            parent = _parent;
        }
    }

    double start_x, start_y, goal_x, goal_y;

    private double heuristic(double s_x, double s_y)
    {
        double x = Math.abs(s_x - goal_x);
        double y = Math.abs(s_y - goal_y);

        return x + y;
    }


    private Node GenerateRelativeNode(Node origin, double dX, double dY, List<Node> closed, List<Node> open)
    {
        double newX = origin.x + dX;
        double newY = origin.y + dY;

        Node temp = new Node(newX, newY, origin.g+1, heuristic(newX, newY), origin);

        for(int i = 0; i < closed.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(closed.get(i).x == temp.x && closed.get(i).y == temp.y)
                return null;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < open.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(open.get(i).x == temp.x && open.get(i).y == temp.y)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }

    private int GetLowestFIndex(List<Node> set)
    {
        double min = 1000000;
        int index = -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < set.size(); ++i)
        {
            double f = set.get(i).h + set.get(i).g;
            if(f < min)
            {
                min = f;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private List<Pair<Double, Double>> PathFromNode(Node _n)
    {
        List<Pair<Double, Double>> path = new ArrayList<Pair<Double, Double>>();
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

        Node curr = _n;
        while(curr.parent != null)
        {
            nodes.add(curr);
            curr = curr.parent;
        }

        //now need to reverse the list.

        for(int i = nodes.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            Pair<Double, Double> pair = pairFromNode(nodes.get(i));
            path.add(pair);
        }

        return path;

    }

    private Pair<Double, Double> pairFromNode(Node _n)
    {
        return new Pair<Double, Double>(new Double(_n.x), new Double(_n.y));
    }

    public static int pathDistance(double start_x, double start_y, double goal_x, double goal_y,
            S3PhysicalEntity i_entity, S3 the_game) {
        AStar a = new AStar(start_x,start_y,goal_x,goal_y,i_entity,the_game);
        List<Pair<Double, Double>> path = a.computePath();
        if (path!=null) return path.size();
        return -1;
    }

    public AStar(double sX, double sY, double gX, double gY,
            S3PhysicalEntity i_entity, S3 the_game) {

        start_x = sX;
        start_y = sY;
        goal_x = gX;
        goal_y = gY;

    }

    public List<Pair<Double, Double>> computePath() {

        double start_h = heuristic(start_x, start_y);
        Node start = new Node(start_x, start_y, 0, start_h, null);
        List<Node> OpenSet = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Node> ClosedSet = new ArrayList<>();

        OpenSet.add(start);

        while(!OpenSet.isEmpty())
        {
            int index = GetLowestFIndex(OpenSet);
            Node N = OpenSet.get(index);
            OpenSet.remove(index);
            if(N.x == goal_x && N.y == goal_y)
            {
                return PathFromNode(N);
            }
            ClosedSet.add(N);
            Node Up = GenerateRelativeNode(N, 0, 1, ClosedSet, OpenSet);
            Node Left = GenerateRelativeNode(N, -1, 0, ClosedSet, OpenSet);
            Node Right = GenerateRelativeNode(N, 1, 0, ClosedSet, OpenSet);
            Node Down = GenerateRelativeNode(N, 0, -1, ClosedSet, OpenSet);

            if(Up != null)
                OpenSet.add(Up);
            if(Left != null)
                OpenSet.add(Left);
            if(Right != null)
                OpenSet.add(Right);
            if(Down != null)
                OpenSet.add(Down);

        }
            return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the stack at the time of the StackOverflow
[image]

The `WPeasant(WTroop).moveTowardsTarget(S3, int, int) line: 202` gets called thousands of times in a row at this point. The code for this function is not in any kind of while loop or for loop or anything.

This could be getting called multiple times however, due to the game object colliding with something, as I have not taken obstructions into account in the pathfinding.

It is hard to say for sure that this is the issue, as I wrote none of this engine, I only have to implement the A*. I can try and include obstacle avoidance and see if this fixes things.

Comment: Learn how to use a profiler. Run your program for a little less time than it usually takes to overflow the stack. Figure out where the memory is being consumed. Fix the problem. It's very hard to guess what's eating memory with only partial code. nb: There are lots of opportunities to improve your A* implementation.  You're not using Java container classes effectively. For example the closed set should be a `Set` rather than a `List` so checking membership is one line of code that runs in constant time, not more  lines that run in linear time.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and use `Set.` Sorry I am unfamiliar with these things, I have never used Java before. When stepping through the code, it appears that the program still has memory, nothing appears out of the ordinary to me, although, I am not the most experienced. Is there anything I should be looking for specifically that jumps out at you?

Comment: Looking into 'Set' it seems to have the drawbacks that I won't be able to get the object back if it is contained, and I also need to grab the open node with the lowest estimated cost to the goal, meaning I would need to create iterators for these pieces of functionality. Also, I don't necessarily want to check if a `Node` is contained in a set, as the objects will not be equivalent, and the only way I could make them so is to overload the equality check, however, as far as I am aware, you cannot do this in Java.

Comment: It will help if you post text of exception. With full stack.

Comment: Then look at `Map`. Also constant time.

Comment: I could potentially use a map, however, I am just trying to get this done quick and dirty before I start making time improvements. Currently, I don't particularly care about the time complexity, I just want to ensure that my code functions and I am not leaking memory or something.

Comment: StackOverflowException can often be caused by a lot of recursive calls, your stack trace shows a lot of recursive 'moveTowardsTarget' calls. You can use the Java `-Xss` option to increase the stack size (specify this in the 'Run Configuration' for your program in the Eclipse 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog).